# Group by 2 columns and sum 2 other columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL noob here with a noob question. I have a table like this:

```
ID   word num_pos num_neg
34   car  1       0
34   car  1       0
100  bus  0       1
123  car  0       1
34   car  0       1
100  bus  1       0
123  bus  0       1
123  car  1       0
```

What I want is a table that groups all the unique IDs AND words  and sums the num_pos and num_neg columns to get the following output:

```
ID   word num_pos num_neg
34   car  2       1
100  bus  1       1
123  car  1       1
123  bus  0       1
```

Also, i would like to filter by word, for example for the word 'car', I would need the following table returned:

```
ID   word num_pos num_neg
34   car  2       1
123  car  1       1
```

I think it would probably be quicker to query the word first, then group by and sum, but I dont know.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: And what was that you tried to do to achieve this?

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use GROUP BY clause on ID and word, and two SUM aggregate functions:

```
SELECT ID, word, SUM(num_pos) sum_npos, SUM(num_neg) sum_nneg
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY ID, word
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bdd9/2).

Answer (score 0):

Touo must read about [**GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
SELECT ID, word, SUM(num_pos) num_pos, SUM(num_neg) num_neg 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY ID, word
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, word, SUM(num_pos), SUM(num_neg)
FROM Sometable
GROUP BY ID, word
```